# mvn package failed because no runnable methods but run junit test in eclipse is ok

Tags: junit, spring-boot, maven-3

Spring boot project, there is a web integration test, when execute it in eclipse (run as > junit test) it's ok.

```
public class ReservationControllerIntegrationTest extends BaseWebIntegrationTest{...}
```

but when run `mvn clean package` , encountered below error:

```
initializationError(com.foo.web.BaseWebIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 0.005 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:140)
```

when I changed

```
public class BaseWebIntegrationTest
```

to

```
public abstract class BaseWebIntegrationTest
```

then run `mvn clean package` again, this time it is build successfully!
So why run junit test in eclipse do not need to specify abstract explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mvn surefire plugin auto-detects test suites based on some simple rules applied to all the classes it finds under `src/main/test`. In particular, it looks for all concrete classes matching a particular naming convention.

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

In your case the plugin thinks that BaseWebIntegrationTest is a test suite, because it matches the naming convention, but it's not finding any test methods in it. When you made the class `abstract` the plugin skipped it because it was no longer instantiable. You could also have renamed the class so that it didn't end in the word `Test`.

When you run the test in Eclipse I'm guessing you run the specific integration test (`ReservationControllerIntegrationTest`) and so Eclipse doesn't try to treat BaseWebIntegrationTest as a test suite.